# Serenity 4.0 - unable to launch the chrome browser -java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder

Tags: serenity-bdd

Unable to launch the chrome browser after upgrade serenity4.0,  when I run the test, I get the below response even after I pass the chrome driver as below: please help
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;

```
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:164)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:142)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:178)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:169)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:120)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.manage(WebDriverFacade.java:370)
```

I have config serenity property file as below: .
webdriver.driver=chrome
and set the property in the below method
public void webdriver_initialization() {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");

```
    getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
    getDriver().manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
    getDriver().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(360));
}
```